# How to implement text selection shadow as in UIWebView in a custom view

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios

Here is a image that shows how Good Reader does it just like in the Web View. 
http://d.pr/mco6

My guess is that there is no easy approach for this except add tons of code to touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnd in the custom view and map location of the string to the offset in the view. (Plus the magnifying glass)

Does anyone have a better solution, or is there something already there I can take advantage of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the picture that looks just like a UITextView with user editing disabled. :) Probably want to have a look at that.

eg:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[myTextView setEditable:NO];
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
```

Comment: It's reading a PDF document, so it's definitely not a UITextView.

Comment: oh dear... maybe qlpreviewcontroller will help you? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html disclaimer: I don't know - its just an idea.. have a look.